# Does IBM MobileFirst 8 supports Ionic 3 and Angular 4

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Does IBM MobileFirst 8 supports Ionic 3 and Angular 4. I have seen blogs and documentation for Ionic 2, what about Ionic 3 ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobilefirst Platform Foundation supports Ionic 3 & Angular 4 and we are targeting to publish a blog on this very soon [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/).

Comment: @JayOrdway Yes IBM Supports and updates MobileFirst. The most recent release was in March 2018. Pl open a separate question if you are seeing specific information on the support status.